# Pygame- Keys held down : some caracters are written more than once when pressing a key

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make an input box.
So we can type something in it.

The first problem I get was when we try to keep a key held for a while, it is repeated only once.
Now this was resolved with the help of the answers done on this link : [Pygame key hold down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331914/pygame-key-hold-down)

However, the problem encountered now, is that when we try to press a key only once, sometimes it is repeated more than once (twice or more commonly).

The pseudo-code looks like this:

`for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                self.quit_screen = True`

```
        # events related to the input box
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            #Things related to it

        #Disactivate the typing on the input box if KEYUP activated
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:         
            self.typing = False
            self.backspace_pressed = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print("KEYDOWN\n")
            if self.user_input_box.input_box_active:
                # If we press 'enter', we save 
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                     #save the text in some variables

                # If we press the key '\b' (backspace), we delete a caracter
                elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.backspace_pressed = True

                else: #Get the current letter
                    self.typing = True
                    self.cur_letter = event.unicode



    if self.typing: #Adding the letter saved in cur_letter to the current text(user_entry)
        self.user_input.user_entry += self.cur_letter  

    if self.backspace_pressed:
        self.user_input.user_entry = self.user_input.user_entry[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a delay to differentiate between pressing once and holding down. You can define some variables like this:

```
self.press_timer = 0
self.already_pressed = False
```

and then, in the key code you can continue to add on this number until it reaches a certain threshold. So...

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    self.press_timer += 1

    if press_timer < 50 and not self.already_pressed:
        # Typing code
        self.already_pressed = True

    elif press_timer > 50 and self.already_pressed:
        # Same code, but without setting already_pressed to True
```

Then, in the pygame.KEYUP code...

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    self.typing = False
    self.backspace_pressed = False
    self.press_timer = 0
    self.already_pressed = False
```

This should allow the leeway to press one key, and then after holding it for a set amount of time, allow the letters to be added endlessly.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I don't know if I didn't really get the point of this solution but it hasn't worked for me

Comment: I have a question concerning your answer. When, for the first time, we press on a key so we have self.press_timer += 1, then with the condition 'if press_timer < 50 and not self.already_pressed:' we have the code of adding the current letter to the input. But if we still holding the key down it won't be repeated for other times cause we have this condition '
    elif press_timer > 50 and self.already_pressed:' that will never get true cause self.press_timer == 1 (it is increased only once).  Please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get key repeats what you are doing is not really the right way to go about it. It is preferable to have the system send you multiple events when it has sensed that a key has been held down. You can get the system to send you repeated KEYDOWN events for a held down key by setting this before you start the event checking loop:

```
pygame.key.set_repeat(delay, interval)
```

You can see more [here in the docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_repeat)

It is turned off by default so you have to enable it.

With respect your current code and why it is repeating when you do nor want it to, you are running the lines:

```
if self.typing: #Adding the letter saved in cur_letter to the current text(user_entry)
    self.user_input.user_entry += self.cur_letter
```

every pass through the event loop, which means that anything event will cause you to execute it. There may events that come through that you may not be expecting. Some like mouse movement events but also other behind the scenes ones you may not realize can occur. You can see what those events are by adding this line at the top of your loop for debugging:

```
print(f"event: {pygame.event.event_name(event.type)}")
```